# Im using gaesessions with flex in a gae web application. but the cookie delete itself between ajax request. why?

Tags: apache-flex

Im using gaesessions with flex in a gae web application. but the cookie delete itself between ajax request. why?

Comment: If a cookie is deleting itself when you're making AJAX requests, what would that possibly have to do with Flex?

Comment: just fixed it. it was a problem with the appengine_config.py file where the cookie key was changing at every request. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just fixed it. it was a problem with the appengine_config.py file where the cookie key was changing at every request. xD